# Find value of integral of sine given the integral of cosine over same limits.

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Is it possible to find the value of - 
$$\int_{t_1}^{t_2}{\sin(\theta(t)) \mathrm{d}t}$$

When one is given the value of - 
$$\int_{t_1}^{t_2}{\cos(\theta(t)) \mathrm{d}t}$$

Where $\theta (t)$ is an unknown function of $t$

Let this known value be $k$

**My Thoughts:**
I thought I could solve the question if I knew the value of - 
$$\int_{t_1}^{t_2}{\cos(\theta(t) + \frac{\pi}{4}) \mathrm{d}t}$$

by expanding using the $\cos(A+B)$ formula. (One could have another angle in place of $\frac{\pi}{4}$).

I was getting stuck because I do not know $\theta (t)$

If somebody could give me a hint in getting from - 
$$\int_{t_1}^{t_2}{\cos(\theta(t)) \mathrm{d}t}$$

to - 
$$\int_{t_1}^{t_2}{\cos(\theta(t) + \frac{\pi}{4}) \mathrm{d}t}$$

I would be grateful.

Comment: If you don't know $\theta(t)$, then knowing $\int_a^b\cos(\theta(t))\,dt$ tells you hardly anything about $\int_a^b\sin(\theta(t))\,dt$.

Comment: do we know anything more about $\theta$ or $t_1,t_2$?

Comment: Take $\theta(t) = t^2$ and you will get 'famous' integrals that don't have a closed form.

Comment: @supinf I would like an answer where we don't know anything about them. But for the question in which I encountered this (which I ultimately solved using another method) we can say that both $t_1$ and $t_2$ are finite and non-negative and $\theta (t)$ is a strictly decreasing function between $t_1$ and $t_2$.

Comment: then i guess it is not possible to make any statement about the two integrals